# Problem executing function from DOM string that goes inside info window Google map object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a React class for this. I declare an empty string (content) which I'm gonna pass to InfoWindow Google map object (inside I have a button with an onClick event). If call it like this:

```
const content = '<button onClick={'+ this.myFunction(myArg) +'}></button>'
```

When I load the page the function gets executed even if I don't press the button.

If I call it like this:

```
const content = '<button onClick={'+ (() => this.myFunction(myArg)) +'}></button>'
```

I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

This is the function where I declare content:

```
showMarker(visit){
  const content = '';
  //Some validations to fill content, for example
  if(visit.boolean){
    content += '<small>' + visit.something + '</small>' //Here concatenation works well
  }
    
  const content += '<button onClick={ this.myFunction(visit) }></button>'
  //Create marker object
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content });
}
```

This is the function from onClick event:

```
myFunction(visit){
  console.log(visit);
}
```

Comment: What about `const content = '<button onClick={ this.myFunction(myArg) }></button>'`

Comment: How exactly are you using `content`? Regardless, the function needs to be part of the string text: `const content = '<button onClick={() => this.myFunction(myArg)}></button>'`

Comment: I tried both answers and they work but the function does not get the parameter. I tried to concatenate it `'<button onClick={ this.myFunction(' + myArg + ') }></button>'` but I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'. This is how I use content: `const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content });`
`

Comment: @MiguelNoriega show more of your code so we test and can come up with a solution

Comment: I updated the question, thanks @Ivan86

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the outer parenthesis?

```
const content = '<button onClick={'+ () => this.myFunction(myArg) +'}></button>'
```

Are you running `this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);` in the constructor?

You could just declare myFunction as a lamda so you don't have to bind it.

```
myFunction = (visit) => {
   console.log(visit);
}
```